# Saving objects with Java

Tags: java, io

I have a question about the following code. I create three instances of my Player class, and then I save them to a file.

```
Player a = new Player(1, "asd");
Player b = new Player(2, "asd");
Player c = new Player(3, "asd");

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Game.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(a);
    oos.writeObject(b);
    oos.writeObject(c);

    oos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What happens with Game.ser? Is this a file that's actually created, or is it just within the program? If not, where is it located? I don't find it in any project folder.

The program works fine. Im just wondering about where the objects are saved.

Comment: The same place you have Game.class (assuming Game is the class you show us).

Comment: It is created in the current working directory where the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the path provided in

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Game.ser");
```

is not absolute, it is created/opened relative to the folder the `java` application was launched from.

In an IDE like Eclipse, the application is usually ran from your Project directory. If your project is in, for example

```
C:\Users\You\workspace\MyApplication
```

the file would be created in

```
C:\Users\You\workspace\MyApplication\Game.ser
```

You can get that path by running

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

The path your provide to the `FileOutputStream`, if it isn't absolute, will be relative to that.

Answer (score 6):

They're saved in the application path. You can use

```
new File("Game.ser").getAbsolutePath()
```

to display their location